# django webapi: dump django model to JSON

Tags: django, json, model

I'm trying to dump django models into JSON format. I've tried to do it like this:

```
import json
from api.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

def users(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(users), content_type="application/json")
```

but it throws following error:

```
[<User: Paul McCartney>, <User: John Lennon>, <User: George Harrison>, <User: Ringo Starr>] is not JSON serializable
```

I know I can iterate through all objects and create a manual list of dictionaries, but I hope there's any better way to do that. Is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from django.core import serializers

data = serializers.serialize('json', User.objects.all())
```

You can get an idea of how you are getting this data on deserialization:

```
import json
json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've found that casting it as a list allows it to be serialized.

```
import json
from api.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

def users(request):
    users = list(User.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(users), content_type="application/json")
```