# How to JSON serialize __dict__ of a Django model?

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary, django-1.7

I want to serialize the values of a single model in Django. Because I want to use `get()`, [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) is not available. However, I read [on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/Jxjdf2LAmXo/hcruIi6VxbIJ) that you can access the values with `__dict__`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
import json
from customer.models import Customer

def single(request, id):
    try:
        model = Customer.objects.get(id=id, user=1)
    except Customer.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    values = model.__dict__
    print(values)
    string = json.dumps(values)
    return HttpResponse(string, content_type='application/json')
```

The print statement outputs this.

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x0000000005556EF0>, 'web
site': 'http://example.com/', 'name': 'Company Name', 'id': 1, 'logo': '', 'use
r_id': 1, 'address3': 'City', 'notes': '', 'address2': 'Street 123', 'address1': 'Company Name', 'ustid': 'AB123456789', 'fullname': 'Full Name Of Company Inc.', 'mail': 'contact@example.com'}
```

Because of the `_state` key that holds an unserializable value the next line fails with this error.

```
<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x0000000005556EF0> is not JSON serializable
```

How can I serialize the dictionary returned from `__dict__` without `_state` being included?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django webapi: dump django model to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155277/django-webapi-dump-django-model-to-json)

Comment: @FallenAngel Serializing what `all()` returns is trivial, but my question is about `get()`. This is related but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`model_to_dict()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L112) is what you need:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

data = model_to_dict(model)
data['logo'] = data['logo'].url
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

By specifying `fields` and `exclude` keyword arguments you can control what fields to serialize.

Also, you can simplify the `try/except` block by using the shortcut [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
model = get_object_or_404(Customer, id=id, user=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the needed import to your question. However, I still can't serialize the dictionary since it contains a Django Image. I think the dictionary would have to contain the image url instead of the whole Django object. Any idea?

Comment: @danijar hm, how does it behave with the image field? Any errors? Also, could you try using built-in queryset serializer like suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1124531/771848)? Thanks.

Comment: `model_to_dict()` returns a dictionary like `{'name': 'Foo', 'user': 1, 'logo': <ImageFieldFile: None>}` which fails to serialize. The Django serializers wrap the fields dictionary in another one which I don't want.

Comment: @danijar ok, I've updated the answer. The idea is to use `model_to_dict()` to get the dictionary, then overwrite the `logo` key. Give it a try. There are other options, but let's first try this one. Thanks.

Comment: I had to check for empty files so `values['logo'] = values['logo'].url if values['logo'] else ''` did the trick. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

check the source code django/core/serializers/**__init__**.py 
comment:

```
Interfaces for serializing Django objects.

Usage::

    from django.core import serializers
    json = serializers.serialize("json", some_queryset)
    objects = list(serializers.deserialize("json", json))

To add your own serializers, use the SERIALIZATION_MODULES setting::

    SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
        "csv" : "path.to.csv.serializer",
        "txt" : "path.to.txt.serializer",
    }
```

for one object

```
json = serializers.serialize("json", some_queryset[0:1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that is is actually possible to use `values()` together with `get()`. You just have to fetch values from a filtered set.

```
def single(request, id):
    user = 1
    try:
        models = Customer.objects.filter(id=id, user=user)
        values = models.values().get()
    except Customer.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    string = json.dumps(values)
    return HttpResponse(string, content_type='application/json')
```