# serializing two different models with django

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-models

I have two models `Property` and `PropertyImage`.
Property holds all the data and PropertyImage is only for allowing an unlimited number of images to be uploaded.

```
 class PropertyImage(models.Model):
     property = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='images')
     url = models.ImageField(upload_to=property_image_name)
```

What I want is to be able to add one field to the serialization of the `Property` class so that it will add the `PropertyImage.url` element. It does not need to be all of the `url` elements that the `Property` has, one would be enough. I am using this for previewing the Property.

Now, I have:

```
results = Property.objects.raw(mysql_query) 
markers = serializers.serialize('json',results)
```

and of course the `PropertyImage` is left out and I can't find a clean way of adding it to the JSON and relating it with the `Property` it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed with [`model_to_dict()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L112):

```
import json
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

results = Property.objects.raw(mysql_query) 
data = []
for result in results:
    model = model_to_dict(result)
    model['image_url'] = model.property_image_set.first().url
    data.append(model)

markers = json.dumps(data)
```

Here's an `image_url` field is set to the [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) `PropertyImage`'s `url` field value for the each `Property` instance in the `results` queryset.

Also see:

- [Django reverse lookup of foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306897/django-reverse-lookup-of-foreign-keys)
- [How to JSON serialize __dict__ of a Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169890/how-to-json-serialize-dict-of-a-django-model/23169930#23169930)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty new to django and web design, and serializers are something I still don't manage well. This really helped.