# Passing an array of objects to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms

I'm trying to view a python list of objects that was a part of some input in an html form:

```
$('input[name=my_array]').serializeObject()
```

where my input tag would be something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_array" value="{{ my_array_of_objects }}">
```

But I'm just getting something like this:

```
[<object_type: an_object object>]
```

So I can't access any properties of this object. Is there a way to convert this to where I can view what these are referencing to? I've been able to iterate over them in previous instances, and access their properties in my HTML file:

```
{% for o in my_array_of_objects %}
   <li> o.id, o.first_name, o.last_name </li>
{% endfor %}
```

So is there a similar way I can access this object in javascript? Sorry if this is noob question.

EDIT: Here is a sample of what I'm trying to pass. I'm using a django rest framework, where my objects are stored in a SQLDB, under python classes like so:

```
class my_object(models.Model):

  study_id = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
  g1 = models.ForeignKey(G1)
  g2 = models.ForeignKey(G2)

  title = models.IntegerField(choices = TITLE_CHOICES)
  family = models.IntegerField(choices = FAMILY_CHOICES)
```

and when a I render some page, I create a list of these objects that I need, let's just call it `my_list_of_objects`. So, in the HTML form, I have an input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_list" value="{{ my_list_of_objects }}">
```

and when I try to reference this value on the JavaScript side after I submit my form, all I get is a list of

```
my_list_of_objects =[<my_object: my_object object>, <my_object: my_object object>, ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you convert that object into a JSON object and access it.

```
JSON.parse($('input[name=my_array]').val());
```

I still didn't get that, how you create that list of object. (may be because I don't know much about Python)

By the way, I suggest you to convert your Python object list to a JSON object in the server page.

```
json.dumps(c.__dict__)
```

I got that line from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408719/2479413). Then you might able to use *JSON.parse* in your java script.

Comment: The value still comes up as `[<object_type: an_object object>]`

Comment: Can you please put the sample data for the input value?

Comment: I added it in the edit, hopefully this explains it a little better

Comment: I feel like it's getting closer? I'm getting a type error now: `<django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x110dd6890> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I'm afraid that I won't be much helpful for that, but have a look on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23169930/2479413)

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.serialize(my_array_of_objects)

Comment: In the form? Or in JavaScript?